# Problems Binding with a GridView UWP

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, gridview, uwp

I have a Binding page for some bugs and another one for comments in my app. The first one work properly, but the second one don't show anything but the data(21 comments) load successfully.
I've been taking a look to the live Live Property Explorer and the first Grid have those options:
[image]

However, the second one have the ItemsSource set as null:
[image]

This should not be possible, because those items have the same code just with few changes to make them load different.
Here you have the code:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Book" x:Key="BookDataTemplate">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Image Width="150" Height="150" Source="{x:Bind CoverImage}" />
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{x:Bind DScore}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF21C721" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{x:Bind DFav}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF9C9C9C" />
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{x:Bind Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{x:Bind Author}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF9C9C9C" />
                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind DData}"/>
                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Books}" AllowDrop="True" IsSwipeEnabled="True" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="Content_ItemClick" Name="Content" Margin="0,100,0,40" CanReorderItems="True" 
                  CanDragItems="True"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BookDataTemplate}" ReorderMode="Enabled"/>
```

And the Comments gridview:

```
    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Comment" x:Key="CommentDataTemplate">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle Margin="50, 0, 0, 30" Fill="#FF144772" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Rectangle Margin="60, 0, 0, 45" Fill="#FF031131" Height="60" Stroke="Black" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <Rectangle Margin="140, 0, 0, 25" Fill="#FF103F91" Height="60" Stroke="Black" Width="360" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="65,18,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Source="Assets/profile.png"/>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Margin="0, 70, 400, 0" FontSize="10" Text="{x:Bind Date}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF9C9C9C" />
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Margin="130, 0, 0, 0" FontSize="16" Text="{x:Bind Author}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock Margin="150, 30, 0, 0" FontSize="11" Text="{x:Bind Body}" Width="360" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FF9C9C9C" />
                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Score}"/>
                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Comments}" AllowDrop="True" IsSwipeEnabled="True" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Name="Content" Margin="0,100,0,40" CanReorderItems="True" 
                            CanDragItems="True"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CommentDataTemplate}" ReorderMode="Enabled"/>
```

Can somebody help me identify the problem here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the XAML file of your 2nd page go to "Comments" in ItemsSource and press F12. If you could navigate to definition of Comments means your binding is successful but Comments is not getting populated. If you could not navigate to definition means binding is not working. In that case check if datacontext has been set for that page. Also check how "Comments" is spelled in XAML and in the property.

Comment: Fixed Thanks for the help!